# Standard SObject which are not exposed by Salesforce

Tags: soql, soap-api, sobject, describesobject, sobjecttype

I would like to know if there is Standard SObject for `Changeset` or `Package`?
I noticed that `033` is prefix for Package and `0A2` is key prefix for Changeset.
However, neither of there objects are not exposed through API or SOQL.
I tried [this code](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-find-Object-Type-from-Record-ID-Prefix&language=en_US)
to run but it returns nothing for `0A2` or `033`.

Is there any reason why SFDC doesn't want to make these objects public for SOQL?

---

Update: also I am interested in `034` which looks like prefix for package component.

Using Adrian Larson's code, it gives `PackageMember`

```
system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, Id.valueOf('03423000000MFWY').getSObjectType());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The key prefix `0A2` corresponds to the `DevelopmentPackageVersion` object.
- The key prefix `033` corresponds to the `AllPackage` object.

A more comprehensive (and significantly faster, I imagine) methodology for taking a key prefix or Id is this fairly simple approach:

```
system.debug(Id.valueOf('0A2000000000000').getSObjectType());
system.debug(Id.valueOf('033000000000000').getSObjectType());
```

Given the prefix only, you can right-pad with zeroes until you get to 15 digits and you will get the same result as if you copy-pasted the whole id.

Comment: you are totally right , I am fool that I didn't find this myself

Comment: Eh that's being too hard on yourself. As for why these objects are not publicly documented or available for query, I'm not sure, but I'm hardly surprised, either.

Comment: Actually knowing the sobject name doesn't help me much, still when I try to make SOQL query (either usual or "Use Tooling API"), it says that "sObject type 'DevelopmentPackageVersion' is not supported." or "sObject type 'AllPackage' is not supported."

Comment: Yeah, I do not believe you actually can query for them, but that's a slightly different question in and of itself, apart from identifying the objects represented by those Ids. I did a bit of searching but didn't find anything just yet.

Comment: Probably I need to open a Salesforce Idea to make them enable these two objects at least for readonly mode for querying

Comment: Yeah, I imagine so. Might take a few years to get any traction. :(